# What's wrong with my code for reversing my encryption code?

Tags: java, string

I have to write a program that uses letter displacement to encrypt a string that is entered by the user.  The code for encryption looks like:

```
for (int j = 0; j<key; j++) {
    for (i = j; i <length; i += key)
    {
        password += phrase.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

This work as I expect.

For example, when I use a key length of 3, it changes

```
Testing1234567890ABCDEF
```

to

```
Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258AD
```

My issue is when I try to undo it.

```
for (int j = 0; j<=Math.ceil(phrase.length()/key); j++){
    for (int i = j; i < phrase.length(); i += Math.ceil((phrase.length()/key))+1)
    {
        password += phrase.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

This works for this phrase at this key but does not work if I use a different phrase or different key.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the results of this - notice that the decrypt is only ever right when the length of the string and the key value are relatively prime.

```
public String encrypt(String s, int key) {
    String encrypted = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
        for (int i = j; i < s.length(); i += key) {
            encrypted += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}

public String decrypt(String encrypted, int key) {
    String decrypted = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= Math.ceil(encrypted.length() / key); j++) {
        for (int i = j; i < encrypted.length(); i += Math.ceil((encrypted.length() / key)) + 1) {
            decrypted += encrypted.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return decrypted;
}

private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).intValue();
}

private void test(String s) {
    for (int key = 1; key < 10; key++) {
        String encrypted = encrypt(s, key);
        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
        boolean good = decrypted.equals(s);
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + encrypted + " -> " + decrypted + "(" + key + ")" + " gcd(" + s.length() + "," + key + ") = " + gcd(s.length(), key) + " " + (good ? "*" : ""));

    }
}

public void test() {
    test("Testing1234567890ABCDEF");
    test("Testing1234567890ABCDEFG");

}
```

prints

```
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(1) gcd(23,1) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Tsig24680BDFetn13579ACE -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(2) gcd(23,2) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258AD -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(3) gcd(23,3) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Ti260Den37AEsg48BFt159C -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(4) gcd(23,4) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Tn49Deg50Es16AFt27Bi38C -> Test3ng1284567C90ABDEFi(5) gcd(23,5) = 1 
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Tg6Be17Cs28Dt39Ei40Fn5A -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(6) gcd(23,6) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> T18Ee29Fs30t4Ai5Bn6Cg7D -> Tes4Bg123An7890i6DEFt5C(7) gcd(23,7) = 1 
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> T20e3As4Bt5Ci6Dn7Eg8F19 -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(8) gcd(23,8) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> T3Be4Cs5Dt6Ei7Fn8g9102A -> Testin923456781ABCDEFg0(9) gcd(23,9) = 1 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(1) gcd(24,1) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Tsig24680BDFetn13579ACEG -> Ttsni1g32547698A0CBEDGFe(2) gcd(24,2) = 2 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258ADG -> Ti2t15g4837A60D9CGBFEsen(3) gcd(24,3) = 3 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Ti260Den37AEsg48BFt159CG -> Tn49i38C27BG6AF0EtDs1eg5(4) gcd(24,4) = 4 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Tn49Deg50Es16AFt27BGi38C -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(5) gcd(24,5) = 1 *
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Tg6Be17Cs28Dt39Ei40Fn5AG -> T18Eng7Di56Ct4ABs30Ge29F(6) gcd(24,6) = 6 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> T18Ee29Fs30Gt4Ai5Bn6Cg7D -> Test5C1234Bg890An7EFGi6D(7) gcd(24,7) = 1 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> T20e3As4Bt5Ci6Dn7Eg8F19G -> T3Bi7F2At6E10s5Dg9e4Cn8G(8) gcd(24,8) = 8 
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> T3Be4Cs5Dt6Ei7Fn8Gg9102A -> Testing034567892BCDEFG1A(9) gcd(24,9) = 3
```

However, just because they are relatively prime doesn't mean that the encrypt/decrypt will work.

Still looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that the update `i += Math.ceil((phrase.length()/key))+1` in your decrypt function should not be constant

```
for (int j = 0; j<=Math.ceil(phrase.length()/key); j++){
    for (int i = j; i < phrase.length(); i += Math.ceil((phrase.length()/key))+1)
    {
        password += phrase.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

To illustrate, say `key=4`, input phrase = `"123456789"`.

After encryption, the password become:
`"159263748"`, the "index" is `048152637`,

meaning the `0th` position of encypted string is taken from the `0th` position of phrase,

`1th` position of encypted string is taken from the `4th` position of phrase, and so on.

After decryption, the decrypted string become:
`"123456789"`, the "index" is `036714682`

meaning the `0th` position of decrypted string is taken from the `0th` position of encrypted string,

`1th` position of decypted string is taken from the `3th` position of encrypted string, and so on.

So your program should read the encrypted string in the sequence of `0->3->5->7->1->4->6->8->2`

note that `0->3` took an increment of 3 while `3->5` took an increment of 2,

your program should address this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that with your method you basically split the input in chunks of fixed size. However, the last chunk may be of different size and therefore you need to take that into account. I encountered this issue when using the key 5, the letter "i" is located at the 19th index instead of the 20th because the last chunk is only 3 characters long (DEF) therefore on the 4th pass the decrypt still reads the 20th (3).

I managed to solve the issue by adding a trailing of symbols (I chose = but you can choose another one) before encrypting and then removing the trailing symbols after decryption. The phrase is always of size multiple of the key before encryption.

Here's the code:

```
private static final char TRAILING_CHAR = '=';     

public static void main(String[] args) {
            test("Testing1234567890ABCDEF");
            test("Testing1234567890ABCDEFG");
       }

    public static String encrypt(String phrase, int key) {
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(phrase.length());
        phrase = trail(phrase, key); //add trailing
        for(int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
            for(int i = j; i < phrase.length(); i+=key) {
                password.append(phrase.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return password.toString();
    }

    public static String decrypt(String phrase, int key) {
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(phrase.length());
        int chunkSize = (int) Math.ceil(phrase.length()/key); //size of chunks
        for(int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++) {
            for(int i = j; i < phrase.length(); i+=chunkSize) {
                password.append(phrase.charAt(i));
            }
        }  
        //remove trailing
        return password.toString().replaceAll(String.valueOf(TRAILING_CHAR), "");
    }

    public static void test(String s) {
        for(int key = 1; key < 10; key++) {
            String trailed = trail(s, key);
            String encrypted = encrypt(s, key);
            String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
            System.out.println(s + " -> "+trailed+" -> " + encrypted + " -> " + decrypted + "(" + key + ")");
        }
    }

    private static String trail(String s, int key) {
        int trailingSize = s.length() % key;
        for(int i = trailingSize;i != 0 && i < key; i++) {
            s += TRAILING_CHAR; //add trailing
        }
        return s;
    }
```

I used the testing procedure from @OldCurmudgeon and it gives me the following output:

```
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(1)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF= -> Tsig24680BDFetn13579ACE= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(2)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF= -> Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258AD= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(3)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF= -> Ti260Den37AEsg48BFt159C= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(4)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF== -> Tn49Deg50Es16AFt27B=i38C= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(5)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF= -> Tg6Be17Cs28Dt39Ei40Fn5A= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(6)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF===== -> T18Ee29Fs30=t4A=i5B=n6C=g7D= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(7)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF= -> T20e3As4Bt5Ci6Dn7Eg8F19= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(8)
Testing1234567890ABCDEF -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF==== -> T3Be4Cs5Dt6Ei7Fn8=g9=10=2A= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEF(9)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(1)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Tsig24680BDFetn13579ACEG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(2)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258ADG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(3)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Ti260Den37AEsg48BFt159CG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(4)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG= -> Tn49Deg50Es16AFt27BGi38C= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(5)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Tg6Be17Cs28Dt39Ei40Fn5AG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(6)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG==== -> T18Ee29Fs30Gt4A=i5B=n6C=g7D= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(7)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> T20e3As4Bt5Ci6Dn7Eg8F19G -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(8)
Testing1234567890ABCDEFG -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG=== -> T3Be4Cs5Dt6Ei7Fn8Gg9=10=2A= -> Testing1234567890ABCDEFG(9)
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.